# Kafka Retention.ms on specific topic is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm creating topic like this in spring boot with **retention time is 10 sec (10000ms)**.

```
@Configuration
public class TopicConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic countersTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("COUNTERS")
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(1)
                .config(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "10000")
                .build();
    }
}
```

After creating topic,you can see that retention time is 10000ms
[image]

I send the message to kafka every **30sec** and I expect that each message should be delete after **10sec.**

But still all the messages are reside in the kafka and Idk but after certain random time, all messages will be deleted.

**Can anyone help me with this ?**

Comment: Take a look to this question other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422479/mystery-about-kafkas-retention-period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka only deletes **closed segments** (assuming the `LogCleaner` is enabled, and running) that are older than the retention period. Notice that you have `segment.bytes` value in your topic config, which defaults to 1GB. So, if your records are very very small, then you'd need to send a lot of them for a new segment to get created, and only then will the retention apply.

In the meantime, the broker will keep all the data.

Comment: I got it and solved the issue. I have total 6 topics and each of them have retention.ms = 30 sec. All of them are getting deleted after segments are getting old but topic COUNTERS is not getting deleted, it'll be deleted when I stop my java program means when producer will disconnect to the kafka and after 18 to 20 sec it's getting deleted. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by counters. As mentioned, segment size matters. Client connections do not

Comment: COUNTERS is basically a topic. And yes you are absolutely correct about segment and I got it. But why only for this topic it's not working. Every other topics are working fine with retention.

Comment: Are you saying data in the topic isn't deleted? Or the topic itself isn't deleted? As mentioned already, the retention.ms is only applicable as a duration that the broker will keep closed log segments. If you're only sending small events every 30 seconds, then you're likely not going to reach the 1GB segment size very quickly, and not within configured 10 second retention period

Comment: Data in the topic is not deleted. But how it's possible that in every other topics data is deleted after retention but only in this topic it's not working. I have only one broker.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer that without knowing how much data is in the topic